# Addressing in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>   
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = 2;
    int *pointer2 = &x;
    int number = &x;
    printf("%x\n",number );
    printf("%x\n",number+1 );
    printf("%x\n",pointer2 );
    printf("%x\n",pointer2+1);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get a warning from gcc that the  "initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]" for the variable number but when i compile i get the following ouput:

```
5da24540
5da24541
5da24540
5da24544
```

Clearly the above thing doesnt happen as we can see on the first two lines of output that the address is only incremented by 1 whereas by 4 in second case.Also please explain that & returns the address which can be assigned to other variables like int's or it is a pointer in it self which can be assigned only to pointer type.

Comment: The output you get is normal. If you add X to a pointer to Y, then X * sizeof Y will be added to the pointer. The size of int is 4 (at least in your case) therefore you get 5da24544 instead of 5da24540.

Comment: The `&` operator yields a pointer. The value of a pointer is called an address. An address can also be considered as an arbitrary integer value, but you don't usually perform numeric manipulations on an address except for the purpose of interfacing with hardware that inspects addresses outside the CPU core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is because of this assignment:

```
int number = &x;
```

You are assigning an `int*` to an `int`, which is nothing you should do. Either (1) assign the value of the `x` to `number`, or (2) change `number`'s type to `int*` (link `pointer2`) and assign the address of `x`.

Or (3) if you really want to assign the address of `x` to `number` use a typecast.

```
// (1)
int number = x; // Assign value of x.
// (2)
int* number = &x; // Assign address of x.
// (3)
int number = (int)&x; // Assign address of x and cast to int.
```

---

Your second question has to do with pointer arithmetic.

Your `number` variable is an `int`, which means if you increment it (`+ 1`) it is literally incremented by 1.

Your `pointer2` variable is an `int*`, which means if you increment it it is incremented by the size of an `int*` (4 byte on 32 bit systems, 8 byte on 64 bit systems).

This is done, so that you can iterate over pointer arrays by simply incrementing the pointer.

There are two reasons the compiler emits a warning:

1) The type mismatch is not handled implicitly by the compiler, because the standard says so. And this in return is since converting from a pointer type to another type has a rare use case. Most of the time assignments like this are made accidentally and the author simply messed up the level of indirection (the number of `*`).

2) Another reason why the standard prohibits this, is that `int` is 4 bytes (in most implementations) and `int*` can be either 4 or 8 bytes depending on the platform compiled for.

Comment: so &x not only returns the address of x but &x is of itself type pointer i.e here int *?

Comment: Yes, the `&` gets the address of the variable and adds one level of indirection to the type, i.e. `int* y = &x; int** z = &y;` etc.

Comment: (3) gives a warning : warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size,may be because the sizeof(int *) is 8 bytes whereas sizeof(int) is 4 bytes on my machine

Comment: That's right. To safely store the address of a pointer in an integral type use `intptr_t`/`uintptr_t` instead of `int`. To do that you may have to `#include <stdint.h>`.

Answer (score 7):

`number` is an `int`, initialized with the address of `x` (makes `int` from address "without cast" - the warning tells you, that this is probably not what you want) - if you increment it, it will be incremented by one.

`pointer2` is a pointer to `int` (initialized with the same address of `x`), incrementing it increments by **size** of `int` (this behaviour is called "pointer arithmetics").

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't convert number from int to pointer. The warning says *"make integer from pointer"*, not *"make pointer from integer"*, so `number` is still an `int`. It's the pointer (the address of `x`) which has been "converted" to a plain integer.

Answer (score 0):

You get the warning because it's not guaranteed that the `int` type can hold a pointer value (for example, you're on a system where `int` is 16 bits but pointer values are 32 bits); if you add a cast, you tell the compiler that you know what you're doing (even if you don't):

```
int number = (int) &x;
```

This tells the compiler that yes, you really want to take the address of `x` and treat it as an ordinary integer.  Just be aware that the value that gets stored to `number` may be truncated.

Nor is it guaranteed that all pointer types have the same size and representation; IOW, a pointer to `int` may be a different size than a pointer to `char`, which may be a different size from a pointer to a `struct`.  On most modern desktop and server architectures they are the same, but there are still some oddball architectures out there where they're not.

As for why you got different results on the additions...

Adding 1 to a pointer gives the address of the next *object* of the pointed-to type; IOW, if you have a pointer to `int`, adding 1 will give you the address of the next available `int`, which is `sizeof (int)` bytes from the current address.  If you have a pointer to a 10-element array of `int`, adding 1 will give you the address of the next 10-element array of `int`, which is `10 * sizeof (int)` bytes from the current address.

This is how array indexing works. The expression `a[i]` is interpreted as `*(a + i)`; that is, compute the address of the `i`'th *element* following `a`, and dereference the result.

Answer (score -1):

Typecast the 'number' assignment and try like this,

```
int x = 2;
int *pointer2 = &x;
int number = (int)&x;
```

This will work.